# In which cases is the Schrodinger representation more useful?

Tags: operators, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, commutator

Dirac in his brilliant book derived quantum mechanics using non-commuting operators $\hat{q}$ and $\hat{p}$.

He related these to the Schrodinger representation using a wavefunction $\psi(x)$ and the operators acting on the wavefunction with $\hat{q}=x$ and $\hat{p}=i\partial_x$.

Now, it seems clear that Dirac preferred his "pure" form of quantum mechanics of non-commuting variables without using the wavefunction representation.

So is the wavefunction really ever needed or can everything be done just using non-commuting variables? If so, why do so many books use both methods? Is it just because the wavefunction is conceptually easier to visualise?

(I for one have never really liked the pure operator formalism as my mind seems to need a concrete representation. Feynman too didn't seem to like the creation/annihilation operator formalism - as in "how can an operator create a particle?" but realised he missed a trick by not learning it.)

Comment: Just as an FYI, this is not usually what one means when talking about the "Schrödinger picture," which typically refers to the formalism of time-dependent states and time-independent operators (c.f. the Heisenberg picture with time-dependent operators and time-independent states).

Comment: Echoing @J.Murray's comment: Is this question about the Schrödinger picture or the Schrödinger representation? They are 2 different things.

Comment: Assuming you want to now about matrix mechanics, here is a [related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38070/is-heisenbergs-matrix-mechanics-or-schrödingers-wave-mechanics-more-preferred) question,  or [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38014/matrix-mechanics-for-those-with-wave-mechanics-background). Operator methods reign supreme when there is symmetry involved, or when connections to QFT are sought. Exposing students and colleagues to the astounding advantages of matrix mechanics invariably gets them to ask how come they did not learn it in school, already...

Comment: An aside on Feynman: I disagree with your implicit impression that Feynman was not in love with algebraic methods. Having known and worked for him, I can assure you he much preferred (clever) algebraic methods and "gimmicks" to differential equations (the common physics background that established dominance of wave over matrix mechanics).  The QM texts by Sakurai and Napolitano or Messiah give you side glimpses of the glories of the "lost matrix kingdom"....

Comment: @Comas I'll see if I can find the quote where he said he hadn't learned them before he created his Feynman diagrams. It's not my impression he actually said this! For someone who thinks in pictures and concrete examples, and not caring about plus and minus signs it doesn't really fit with someone who likes manipulating symbols. Maybe he changed his mind later in life. e.g. page 144 "The Genius of Feynman Diagrams"

Comment: Also here: https://www.aip.org/history-programs/niels-bohr-library/oral-histories/5020-3

Comment: Well, he says there he learned the ladder techniques "like a little child" and mastered them instantly to catch Case's error... (Echt RPF). That was in the late 40s. By the 1970s, he certainly was using second quantization ladder combinatorics like anybody else, except better. Anyone witnessing his passion for fractional Fourier transforms and Jacob-Wick's helicity formalism could not be left in doubt about his instinctive love of algebra...

Comment: Just because you use something. Doesn't mean you like it!