# Lectures on Quantum Mechanics based on Matrix Algebra

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, linear-algebra

I like John S. Townsed's textbook titled *A modern Approach to Quantum Mechanics*, which relies on linear algebra (as opposed to, say, wave mechanics) as its primary mathematical tool. Is there any (good) video lecture using this textbook? Or any (good) video lectures on QM based on a similar approach?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38014/2451

Comment: Hi Anti-Tachyon, Res. recom. qs are restricted on Phys.SE and do usually not distinguish between videos and books.